# ¿El Shell de Linux ejecuta primero fflush(stdout) antes de ejecutar y escribir el resultado del comando pasado por el usuario?

Tags: linux, shell, prompt, stdout

Digamos que quiero saber mi directorio de trabajo actual, así que escribo `pwd` en el prompt y presiono Enter.

Antes de obtener la ruta de mi directorio de trabajo actual, ¿el Shell de Linux ejecuta `fflush(stdout)` **PRIMERO** y luego hace lo que tiene que hacer para devolver la ruta?

Si es así, ¿por qué?

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que `pwd` suele ser un comando del propio shell (aunque exista un binario `/bin/pwd` el shell no lo usa si contiene su propia implementación, como es el caso de bash) yo asumo que al poner `pwd` el shell simplemente consulta la variable donde tiene almacenado ese valor y lo vuelca a stdout. Obviamente eso colocará el resultado _después_ de cualquier otra cosa que hubiera en stdout, por lo que en pantalla lo verás también después, lo que posiblemente te ha hecho pensar que se hace un fflush() antes.

Comment: De todas formas no estaría mal que pusieras algo más de contexto para entedender mejor tu duda. Es decir ¿por qué lo preguntas?

Comment: Es simplemente que no entiendo bien para que sirve la función fflush(), sé que su descripción dice que limpia el buffer, pero tiendo a pensar que, sí la Shell es un programa al que le pasarás N comandos por el prompt, una vez (esta Shell) los ejecute exitosamente, esta (Shell) debería limpiar lo que tenía en el stdout para así disponer de este para el próximo comando que sea pasado, y así... Es esta analogía correcta? @abulafia

Comment: Qué pasaría sí fuese otro comando como ls, cd, doble punto .. ?

Comment: `cd` también lo gestiona el shell. `ls` sí sería un comando externo. En todo caso sí es probable que el shell haga un `fflush()` entre comandos, tendría sentido. Lo que ocurre con stdout es que es _buffereada_, es decir, que cuando un comando vuelca algo a stdout no se ve inmediatamente por la terminal, pues queda guardado en un buffer. Normalmente un retorno de carro (\n) causa que el buffer sea volcado, pero si el programa termina sin haber emitido ningún \n, es posible que su salida no sea visible. Un fflush forzaría ese volcado y lo haría visible.

Comment: Yo creo que el shell debería hacer un fflush justo antes de mostrar su prompt.

Comment: Cuando dices que el Shell haga un ```fflush()``` entre comandos, te refieres a que por ejemplo, sí yo paso ```ls -l```, el haría un ```fflush(stdout)``` una vez ejecute exitosamente el comando ```ls``` para luego ejecutar su argumento ```-l``` y luego nuevamente hacer ```fflush(stdout)```, o en realidad ejecutaría todo el comando con argumento ```ls -l``` y una vez hecho, ahí sí hace ```fflush(stdout)```?

Comment: `ls -l` es un solo comando. Las opciones no son comandos. El shell se limita a lanzar un subproceso dentro del cual carga el ejecutable `ls` y le pasa como parámetros el resto de cosas que se hayan escrito en esa línea. A partir de ahi, el shell se quita de enmedio, quedando a la espera de que ese proceso termine, y cediendo la salida estándar a ese proceso. Cuando el proceso termina, el shell se reanuda e imprime su prompt (`$`). Yo entiendo que justo antes del prompt hará un `fflush()` para que sea visible completa la salida del comando que acaba de terminar.